# jQuery click() event; how to prevent this event on right mouse btn click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
 $("#test_img").click(function() {
   alert("Hello");
 });
</script>
```

But it doesn't matter what mouse button I'm pressing - right or left. I see absolutely the same result. I want alert to be shown only on left mouse button click.

Thank you and sorry; I'm little new to javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can evaluate the [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) attribute to determine which button has been pressed.

```
$("#test_img").mouseup(function(e) { 
  // e.which is 1, 2 or 3 for left / middle / right mouse button
  if (e.which === 1) {
    //continue
  }
});
```

Furthermore, to safely detect a mousebutton, you cannot use the `click`-event! Use `mousedown` or `mouseup` instead.

> [**Try it out here!**](http://jsbin.com/utiha/2)

Comment: Thank you for such detailed comment.